# I fetched the data from Excel individually but I want to fetch all the data using for loop

Tags: cypress

```
/// <reference types="cypress"/>

beforeEach(function(){
    cy.fixture('kirantext').then((data)=>{
   
    this.data=data
    })
})

it('Test',function(){
    cy.log(this.data)
    cy.log(this.data.email)
    cy.log(this.data.password)
    cy.log(this.data.BusinessTypes)
    cy.log(this.data.Name)

})
```

I wrote this code for fetching data individually. Now I need to fetch all the data from Excel using a for loop.

Comment: Hey Kiran! Can you provide some more information about what your "excel" data looks like? What does an individual piece of data look like? What does several pieces look like?

Comment: Hello sir, this my json which is coverted from excel to json. Now i want to read all these details using for loop

{
"BusinessTypes": "Testcase-1",
"Name": "Kiran Ghorpade",
"FIELD2": "Y",
"FIELD4": "Business Types",
"password": "netscout1",
"email": "administrator",
"sirname":"Ghorpade"

}

Comment: Do you have multiple of these JSON Objects, or just the one? Also what exactly do you need to do with the data? Just log it to the console?

Comment: yes i have multiple of these Json objects. For multiple test cases i need to do end to end testing